# Accessing Sitecore content from ASP.NET

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

In one of my project I am trying to retrieve some content from Sitecore (multilingual). Can anyone here point me to the right direction/ best way of doing it? I have seen in some of the posts it’s mentioned about the web service or REST API. Can anyone point to a documentation or code snippet on how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

This is quite a vast topic, but Sitecore doesn't limit you here. The general note about it is mentioned in paragraph 1.2.7 "Web Services, AJAX, and other Internet Interfaces" of [this article](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/reusing_and_sharing_data-a4.pdf).

I would recommend you to explore the standard Sitecore web service (it is present in any Sitecore release). Type `http://yourhost/sitecore/shell/webservice/service.asmx` to get an idea of what it can offer. It consists of just basic operations, but those are enough for the most of cases.